# Getting UserID instead of UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, authentication

I'm working on a simple Web Application with C# MVC. It's a log in page. When I'm trying to log in to the system, there's a public Login function which is gets the Username & Password.

This is it:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new Entities2();

        var user = db.DEV001_Users.FirstOrDefault(u => 
            u.Username == model.Username && 
            u.Password == model.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.DEV001_Users_Id.ToString(), 
                model.RememberMe);

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

On the other hand, I've got another controller, called HomeController, which gets the User DB data (Name, Email, Surname, etc.):

```
var db = new Entities2();
var Username = User.Identity.Name;
var users = db.DEV001_Users.Where(u => u.EmailAddress.ToLower() == Username.ToLower());
var UserModel = new DEV001_Users();

if (users != null)
{
    var user = users.First();
    UserModel.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
    UserModel.GivenName = user.GivenName;
    UserModel.Surname = user.Surname;
}

return View(UserModel);
```

Now, the problem is, when I want to get the UserName with User.Identity.Name, it's giving me the ID of that record, instead of the Username.  I don't know what else to do.

Comment: A side comment, this code `u.Password == model.Password` looks wrong, because you should never compare passwords in plain text. You must have passwords hashed and salted and then compare the result bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will keep that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the ID instead of the name because you are putting the ID instead of the name in the auth cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.DEV001_Users_Id.ToString(), model.RememberMe);
```

Whatever value you set in the cookie is what you are going to get in `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you were right. Thanks very much my friend, you've saved my night :D

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are getting different results in the two functions as you are accessing different fields: in the first, `user.DEV001_Users_Id` which is presumably an integer, and in the second `user.EmailAddress` and others.

Here's the thing: you already have the username in `model.Username`. You are in fact querying with it as part of the `where` clause you have supplied to [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039(v=vs.100).aspx) so we know for a fact that `model.Username` is the username in this `DEV001_Users` row.

So, once you have verified that the user exists in the database and performed any other checks you might be doing, such as checking they are not banned, you can modify your code to the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
```

I'm not too keen on the implication here that you are storing the passwords in plain text, by the way.

Comment: I will change the password security too, thanks for your answer my friend.